# How can I change the desktop icons on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, desktop-icons

20.04 seems to have lost the ability to change desktop icons by right clicking them and changing the icon in the Properties window. You can still see the new icon in the files, but it does not update on the desktop. Does any one know a workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure about a workaround, but this may be worth reporting as a bug, assuming that you have not made any modifications to your system that could affect this.